# Is a Ruby global variable equivalent to a class variable on Class Object?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, inheritance

I'm still fairly new to web development (well, all development), building an e-commerce app with Ruby on Rails for my porfolio.  I'm using Redis for caching and to build a simple shopping cart (myself, not using a gem).

In addition to Rails, I've also stitched together a few simple apps using the MERN (Node, Express, Mongo, ReactJS) stack to boost my JavaScript skills.

In the course of copy-pasta'ing code for my Redis initializer (config/initializers/redis.rb), I observed some global variables:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  $redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])
else
  $redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
end
```

Because: JavaScript, I know that global variables make Baby Jesus cry or Mighty Zeus goes a big rubbery one or nothing, whatever (freedom of/from religion, etc)...

I know JavaScript and Ruby are vastly different animals:

1) JS: My understanding is that variables set outside the "outer" function's scope are global in context and store a location to the assigned value.

2) Ruby: $global_variable, @@class_variable, @instance_variable

3) "Everything" in Ruby is an object (except blocks and individual index items within an array), including classes, primitives, etc.

4) A Ruby Class, if it does not explicitly inherit from any another Class, inherits from the Object Class.

5) A Rails application's 'config/initialize' directory contains files that an instance of a Rails application should (wait for it) initialize:

Looking at my config/initializers/redis.rb file (code included above), the context is not explicit (i.e. there is no Class/Module/etc).

So...

6) config/environment.rb contains this code:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

7) config/application.rb contains:

```
require_relative 'boot'
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Ecom
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those 
specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in 
config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.cache_store = :redis_store, 
"redis://localhost:6379/0/cache", { expires_in: 90.minutes }
  end
end
```

8) Per the appropriate Rails Guide:
  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-application

```
Rails.application.initialize!
```

This (wait for it) "initializes" an instance of the Rails app object.

9)  The Rails.application object is an instance of Class Application (???)

Thank you for your time; given the above, here are my questions:

A)  Is the Rails.application object actually an instance of the Application Class?

B) This was my original question, I included the above because I felt this simple question, without any context, might seem vague or unclear:

Is there any difference between a Ruby global variable:

```
$var = "A Ruby global variable"
```

and

```
Class Object
  @@var = "A class variable set on the Class Object"
end
```

I couldn't find this exact question addressed anywhere, my apologies if I missed something.

Are these functional equivalents, if not exact equivalents?

Is Class Object, as the Class from which all other Classes/Objects ultimately inherit, therefore, Ruby's "global" context (or not, and I missed something huge)?

C) (added as an edit) Because a global variable needs to be initiated and is available in a global scope, it is a class variable and not an instance variable.   Is that reasoning sound?

Assuming I am correct in thinking that global variables and class variables are (at least) functionally equivalent, global variables are available "everywhere" because "everything" inherits from Class Object.

D)  After considering the first comment, this might all have been better expressed along the chicken/egg paradigm?

If a global variable is an object, it has to inherit from Class Object, right?  This would mean the "global" context is still wrapped within Class Object.

Comment: dont know all the answers, but i'd say for question B, they're different. Global variable is a single thing available to all scope. The instance var you have would be available on every object & class, but not in global scope. So a global variable is not a class variable, as it's not defined on any class.

Comment: But that global variable is also an object.  Ergo, ipso facto:  $var = "a global variable" inherets from Class Object...   Right?

Comment: That's a lot of latin and logic. The only answer to which is another beer.

Comment: Cheers.  And I just reread @agmcleod 's comment in an angry, sheep-throwing Scottish accent.

Comment: TLDR, could you please make a question shorter?

Comment: Apologies for the length, I was writing and formulating the question simultaneously.  At the time, it seemed the best, possibly only, way to get the answers I was looking for.   If you have ADD, you can recognize the stream-of-conciousness, but I accept that next time I should be more succint.

Comment: Why did you tag this as `javascript`?!

Comment: "If a global variable is an object" - variables __aren't__ objects. They _point_ to objects.

Comment: #8 - `Rails.application.initialize!` does not initialize an instance of the Rails app object. It runs the initializers for the Rails application (best known ones in `config/initializers`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) JS: My understanding is that variables set outside the "outer" function's scope are global in context

This depends on what *exactly* you mean by "variables". Variables declared with `const` or `let` are lexically scoped.

Variables declared with `var` in the top-level context aren't actually variables at all, they become properties of the top-level object (e.g. `window`, `document`, `global`, … depending on your environment).

> and store a location to the assigned value.

That is true of all variables in both Ruby and ECMAScript, as well as properties in ECMAScript.

> 3) "Everything" in Ruby is an object (except blocks and individual index items within an array), including classes, primitives, etc.

This *really* depends on what exactly you mean by "everything". There are lots of "objects" (in the sense of "things we can talk about") in Ruby that aren't "objects" (in the sense of "things we can assign to variables, pass around, manipulate in Ruby code"). For example, variables aren't objects in Ruby.

> A)  Is the Rails.application object actually an instance of the Application Class?

I have no idea what this has to do with global variables.

> Is there any difference between a Ruby global variable:
>
> ```
> $var = "A Ruby global variable"
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> Class Object
>   @@var = "A class variable set on the Class Object"
> end
> ```

Yes, there is the pretty obvious difference that objects and classes which don't have `Object` in their ancestors chain won't have access to `Object`'s class variables:

```
class BasicObject
  @@var
end
# NameError: uninitialized class variable @@var in BasicObject
```

> Is Class Object, as the Class from which all other Classes/Objects ultimately inherit, therefore, Ruby's "global" context (or not, and I missed something huge)?

The `Object` class acts as a sort-of global context for some stuff, but that is not because it is global, but rather because it is the parent of most classes (basically anything that doesn't extend directly from `BasicObject`).

Anything that uses inheritance (class variables, methods, and constants) and is defined in `Object` will also be available in everything that descends from `Object`. But that has nothing to do with "global". That's just how inheritance works. Note that `Object` itself inherits from `Kernel` and `BasicObject`, so this is true for anything defined in those two as well.

> C) (added as an edit) Because a global variable needs to be initiated and is available in a global scope, it is a class variable and not an instance variable.   Is that reasoning sound?

No, it is not. A global variable is neither an instance variable nor a class variable. It is a global variable.

> If a global variable is an object, it has to inherit from Class Object, right?  This would mean the "global" context is still wrapped within Class Object.

Variables aren't objects in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

> Is a Ruby global variable equivalent to a class variable on Class Object?

No:

```
$x = "hello"

class Object 
  @@y = "goodbye"
  p class_variables
end

--output:--
[:@@y]
```

> Are these functional equivalents, if not exact equivalents?

No:

```
$x = 'hello'

class Animal
  @@y =  'goodbye'
end

class Dog < Animal
  def show
    puts $x
    puts @@y
  end
end

Dog.new.show

class BasketBall
  def show
    puts $x
    puts @@y
  end
end

BasketBall.new.show

--output:--
hello
goodbye
hello

1.rb:19:in `show': uninitialized class variable @@y in BasketBall (NameError)
    from 1.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

`@@ variables` aren't used in ruby--they are considered a design flaw. `$ variables` are rarely used.  The key variable types are:

```
x       => local variable
@x      => instance variable
```

There is also what's known as a *class instance* variable, which is what rubyists use for *class variables*.  You create a *class instance* variable by assigning to it outside of any defs:

```
class Animal
  class <<self
    attr_accessor :x
  end

  @x =  'animal'   #<******* class instance variable *********
end

class Dog < Animal
  def show
    puts Animal.x
  end
end

d1 = Dog.new
d1.show   #=>animal
d2 = Dog.new
d2.show   #=>animal

Animal.x = 'rock'

d1.show  #=>rock
d2.show  #=>rock
```

> 1) JS: My understanding is that variables set outside the "outer"
>   function's scope are global in context and store a location to the
>   assigned value.

They become properties of the `window` object.

> A Ruby Class, if it does not explicitly inherit from any another
>   Class, inherits from the Object Class.

All ruby objects inherit from Object--even if they inherit from another class:

```
class Object
  def greet
    puts 'hello'
  end
end


class Animal
end

class Dog < Animal
end

Dog.new.greet

--output:--
hello
```

> A) Is the Rails.application object actually an instance of the
>   Application Class?

```
> $ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7)
2.3.0 :001 > x = Rails.application
...
...
2.3.0 :002 > x.class
 => Test4::Application
```

> But that global variable is also an object. Ergo, ipso facto: $var =
>   "a global variable" inherets from Class Object... Right?

No variable in ruby is an object.

> I'm still fairly new to web development (well, all development)

Rails uses a lot of black magic, and "black magic" is an intermediate to advanced ruby topic.  You didn't say where you are in your ruby learning, but if you want to learn about the wild stuff that you can do with ruby, you should read "Metaprogramming Ruby".

Comment: Example in your second section is flawed. The question specifically mentions "class variable on class `Object`" (the common superclass for all the things, so its class variables _should_ be accessible everywhere)

Comment: "they are considered a design flaw" - citation needed.

Comment: I'm accepting this just to close and rewrite as a fresh question or see if I can't figure it out myself.